# RewriteRule doesn't work as I want

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a small problem.
I have a color-customization code for an image, and I use RewriteRule to make it shorter:

```
RewriteRule ^cc-(.*?)-(.*?)\.png$ cc.php?col1=$1&col2=$2 [L]
```

When I enter localhost/Gen/cc-1122ff-ffffff.png it opens for me normally.
But, when I want to add text to this generated picture with PHP I use another RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^sig,(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),([^,]+),(.*?),([^,]+)\.png$ test.php?nam=$6&font=$5.ttf&bg=$7.png&gn=$1&badg=$2&typ=$3&itm=$4 [L]
```

And I go to this link: localhost/Gen/sig,y,y,mem,no,Pixel,test,cc-1122ff-ffffff.png
I get this error:

```
Warning: imagecreatefrompng(cc-1122ff-ffffff.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\Xampp\htdocs\Gen\test.php on line 31
```

The second RewriteRule normally works, for example with localhost/Gen/sig,y,y,mem,no,Pixel,test,white.png
Second RewriteRule doesn't work with first RewriteRule. Why?

Comment: Well, to start with, the first one ends with `[L]` which identifies it as the "last" rule (no others are run if that one matches). You should post the entire relevant configuration (<vhost> or .htaccess) in any event to help pinpoint the error.

Answer (score 1):

`imagecreatefrompng` does not make an HTTP request when the URL is relative (like `cc-1122ff-ffffff.png`); it treats it as a file path.

If you make the URL absolute, like `localhost/Gen/sig,y,y,mem,no,Pixel,test,http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FGen%2Fcc-1122ff-ffffff.png`, imagecreatefrompng will treat it as a URL, not a file path.